# ZeroClipboard js is not worlink with Input[type="text"]

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

I am facing a problem with ZeroClipoard js. I want to copy text which an user put on a input form field when he click on a button. I am not good in js. So can anyone plz help me?
Thanks in advance.

Below is my code.

HTML markup:

```
<p class="formwidth3">
    <label for="">Sales Page Link / URL</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="salesinput2" name="salesinput2" class="formwidth" value="" onchange="updatePreview();" />
</p>
<p class="formicons ok1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default link" id="copy-button" title="Click to copy."></button>
</p>
```

main.js code:

```
//set path
ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath("ZeroClipboard.swf");
//create client
var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
//event

clip.setHandCursor( true );

clip.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
clip.setText(document.getElementById("salesinput2").value);
});
clip.addEventListener("complete", function (client, text) {
alert("copied: " + text);
});
//glue it to the button
clip.glue("copy-button");
```

Comment: What is the problem that is happening? What have you tried?

Comment: When anyone click on the button with an id "copy-button", the value from input with an id "salesinput2" will be copy. @ub3rst4r